# Accessing Data from axios on a view Node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, pug

I'm trying to print the data from an axios request to a pug template. I'm having issues with access the data. I'm new to this and I think it has something to do with my data object being passed in to the route.

The Backend

```
    axios.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
        .then(res => {
            const data = [];
            const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
            $('.maincounter-number').each((index, element) => {
                const numberData = $(element).text();
                data[0] = {numberData: numberData};
                //console.log(data);
            });
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error fetching and parsing data: ", err);
    });


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home', data: data});

});
```

The front end

```
  p #{data.numberData}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with scoping. The data variable is bound to local scope.

```
async function scrapeWorldOMeter(){
   try{
       const worldOMeterResponse = await axios.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/");
       const data = [];
       const $ = cheerio.load(worldOMeterResponse.data);
       $('.maincounter-number').each((index, element) => {
       const numberData = $(element).text();
       data[0] = {numberData: numberData};
       return data[0];
   });

   }
   catch(err){
       throw new Error(`Can't scrape WorldOMeter ${err}`)
   }
}


app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
const data = await scrapeWorldOMeter()
res.render('index', {title: 'Home', data});
});
```

Comment: Adhilkari, I've implemented your code and It still does not show on the view. Additionally, I've console.log(data) in the route just before the index view is rendered and it returns undefined.

Comment: return {numberData}
From scrapeWorldOMeter function it will work